# Multiple widget views

Tags: apostrophe-cms

When selecting a type to display widgets from it would be nice to be able to have the option of selecting between several widget.html templates, similar to the way you can select a template when creating a new page.

Is this possible somehow already?

Answer (score 0):

You can include a `subType` field in your widget's schema:

```
addFields: [
  {
    name: 'subType',
    type: 'select',
    choices: [
      {
        value: 'red',
        label: 'Red'
      },
      {
        value: 'blue',
        label: 'Blue'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then, in your `widget.html` file, you can write:

```
{% include data.widget.subType + '.html' %}
```

Now create `red.html` and `blue.html` templates and you should be off to the races.

Hope this is helpful!